# TeXStudio and GSview problem: file .ps does not exist

Tags: miktex, texstudio, postscript

I have updated TeXStudio and now, when I compile, all work without errors. But If I "compile and view" or simple "view" The answer is:

> `File 'path\paper.ps' does not exist`

from GSview.

Till yesterday, I had not any kind of this problem. Today I add the command `\hyphenation` in the code, but TeXStudio and MiKTeX work fine and I have my PDF output without errors.

Comment: Do compile as `.ps` or `.pdf`? Perhaps you compile with pdfLaTeX which create a PDF and try to open a postscript file?

Comment: I compile as `.pdf`, but I see this error for the first time.

Comment: I don't really know TeXStudio but an option to show the output may have change and try to show a postscript which leads to the error. But I don't know how to overcome this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solve in this way:

> `TeXStudio -> Menu -> Options -> Restore Default Settings...`

Unfortunately, in this way I can not say you where is the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This topic is quite old, but I just had the same issue and found a solution.
For some reason, an update changed the "**Default Viewer**" in **Options > Configure TeXstudio > Build**. I simply copied the line from the PDF Viewer command (for me *txs:///view-pdf-internal --embedded*). I have not encountered this with build and view, but if you do the script might have changed for ps viewer. For an embedded pdf : *txs:///pdf-chain*.

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I just into the same issue. I realized that for some reason the default viewer has changed to "txs:///view-ps" as soon as switched it back to "txs:///view-pdf" everything just worked fine again.

TexStudio -> Options -> Build -> Default Viewer